# In $R^n$ with the Euclidean metric let $A = \{(x_1,..., x_n) : x_n = 0\}$. Calculates $A^◦$ and $Fr(A)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to find $A^◦$ and $Fr(A)$ ($A^°=$ interior points of a set
$Fr(A)=$ boundary points of a set) but I don't have a mental representation of the sequence.

I tried setting $n=3$ to get an idea. But if I consider $n=1$ then, under that case $A^◦=\emptyset$

Also, if I make a ball with center in some element of the sequence, that ball would be in A and in its complement. So, could you ensure that $A=Fr(A)$?

Comment: $A^\circ$ and $Fr(A)$ are not standard notation, so you might want to define them.

Comment: $A^°=$ interior points of a set
$Fr(A)=$ boundary points of a set

Comment: Put it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=(x_1,x_2,..,x_n) \in A$ and $B(x,r) \subseteq A$ then $y=(\frac  1 k, x_2,x_3,...) \in B(x,r)$ and $y \notin A$ provided $k$ is so large that $\frac  1 k <r$. Hence, $B(x,r) \subseteq A$ is not possible for any $r>0$. This proves that $A$ has empty interior. I will let you prove that $A$ is closed. These facts show that $Fr(A)=A$.